# Request-Promise-Native ignores specified headers

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I am somewhat new to Nodejs. I am working on a pair of Microservices, and I need one to post data to the other.  I am using the request-promise-native library.

My code is to make the call is like this:

```
  const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: url,
            formData: {
                command: command,
                version: version,
                session_id: sid,
                aicc_data: data
            },
            headers: {
                'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }

         rp(options)
```

However, when I inspect the request as it come in to the other server, the header I have specified does not appear.

```
headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------395968157759002211606136',
  host: 'localhost:9000',
  'content-length': '513',
  connection: 'close' }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options` includes a `formData` object which enforces `multipart/form-data`.

You should [add the `form` object instead when you want to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://github.com/request/request#applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-url-encoded-forms).

Comment: how do you achieve that in request-promise?
you are referring to request documentation. 

thanks

Comment: @GalMargalit ["Since request-promise wraps around request everything that works with request also works with request-promise."](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise#cheat-sheet) So it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: thanks, I'm meeting some difficulties. will give it a few more shots